# JQuery Animate functions jumps to the top of screen before animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scrolltop

I'm relatively new to Jquery so please feel free to slap me if this is obvious. I have this little piece of script which will move a div by it's margin and scroll the browser to the new content. When applied the page jumps to the top and then jumps back and then animated. Here is the JS.

```
     var onoff = true;

     $('#archive').click(function() {

        if(onoff == true)
        {
            $('#footer').animate({marginTop: 0}, 300);
            onoff = false;

        } else
        {
            $('html, body').animate({
                 scrollTop: $("#archive").offset().top
             }, 2000);

            $('#footer').animate({marginTop: -171}, 300);
            onoff = true;
        }

     });
```

Any help would be appreciated and sorry if this is a duplicate question, I couldn't find one if it is.

Thanks,
-S

Comment: Without seeing your HTML I can't comment too much. But an element's style properties can be very important to how an element is animated. Just a thought, try using padding or implementing a height instead of using margin.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the height and padding. I'll definitely try implementing that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably because you need a preventDefault

```
$('#archive').click(function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault()

...
```